# How do I create this relationship in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, join, foreign-keys, phpmyadmin

I'm following along with a book that wants me to create the following relationships in my database:

```
ALTER TABLE 'tbl_issue' ADD CONSTRAINT 'FK_issue_project' FOREIGN KEY ('project_id') REFERENCES 'tbl_project' ('id') ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
ALTER TABLE 'tbl_issue' ADD CONSTRAINT 'FK_issue_owner' FOREIGN KEY ('owner_id') REFERENCES 'tbl_user' ('id') ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
ALTER TABLE 'tbl_issue' ADD CONSTRAINT 'FK_issue_requester' FOREIGN KEY ('requester_id') REFERENCES 'tbl_user' ('id') ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
ALTER TABLE 'tbl_project_user' ADD CONSTRAINT 'FK_project_ user' FOREIGN KEY ('project_id') REFERENCES 'tbl_project' ('id') ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
ALTER TABLE 'tbl_project_user' ADD CONSTRAINT 'FK_user_ project' FOREIGN KEY ('user_id') REFERENCES 'tbl_user' ('id') ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

When I try to run the SQL, I get an error like:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''tbl_issue' ADD CONSTRAINT 'FK_issue_project' FOREIGN KEY ('project_id') REFEREN' at line 1
```

So, I want to try doing it (visually) in phpMyAdmin. How do you do that?

DB SQL:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.3.9.2
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: May 24, 2011 at 01:27 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.9
-- PHP Version: 5.3.5

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

--
-- Database: `trackstar`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_issue`
--

CREATE TABLE `tbl_issue` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `project_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `owner_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `requester_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_issue`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_project`
--

CREATE TABLE `tbl_project` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `create_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_project`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_project_user`
--

CREATE TABLE `tbl_project_user` (
  `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `create_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`project_id`,`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_project_user`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_user`
--

CREATE TABLE `tbl_user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_login_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_user`
--
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use backticks, like so:

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl_issue`
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_issue_project` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`)
    REFERENCES `tbl_project` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

Comment: That did it! So, is it possible to manage this relationship from within phpMyAdmin at all (without SQL)?

Comment: Edit: the indexes can be specified below the table listing and the relationships (REFERENCES) can be specified by clicking "Relationships" next to "Print".

Comment: But since you already have the queries, it's probably faster to fix them then to use the "Relationships" of phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the quotes from around the table names - the quotes make MySQL think you're altering a string, not a table:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_issue ADD CONSTRAINT 'FK_issue_project' FOREIGN KEY ('project_id') REFERENCES tbl_project ('id') ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```